# Parse HTML uploaded CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, html-parsing

I am using GAE to host a website which needs inputs from a CSV file. After this csv file has been uploaded, I will convert it to a table. However, I met the problem about Mac and Windows compatibility issue. The CSV file generated in Mac will not be recognized, and I got the error:

```
new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Here is my
Python CODE

```
def loop_html(thefile):
    reader = csv.reader(thefile.file)   
    header = reader.next()
    i=1
    iter_html=""
    for row in reader:
        iter_html = iter_html +html_table(row,i)  #generate inputs table
        i=i+1

def html_table(row_inp,iter):
    mai_temp=float(row_inp[0])

    Input_header="""<table border="1">
                        <tr><H3>Batch Calculation of Iteration %s</H3></tr><br>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Input Name</b></td>
                            <td><b>Input value</b></td>
                            <td><b>Unit</b></td>
                        </tr>"""%(iter)
    Input_mai="""<tr>
                    <td>Mass of Applied Ingredient Applied to Paddy</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>kg</td>
                </tr>""" %(mai_temp) 
    Inout_table = Input_header+Input_mai
    return Inout_table
```

Later I changed the code 'reader = csv.reader(thefile.file) ' to 
'reader = csv.reader(open(thefile.file,'U')) ' which gave me different types of error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, cStringIO.StringO found
```

Can anyone take a look at my code and give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution. 'splitlines()' will handle the new line issue. Here is the [source](http://madebyknight.com/handling-csv-uploads-in-django/).

```
reader = csv.reader(thefile.file.read().splitlines())
```